# Likelihood the wordle of the day is sampled as a uniform distribution from the entire wordle word list

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been playing the wordle a lot recently. I noticed early on that misspellings on my part were 'accepted' as valid words, but that the answer was always a well known word. Recently I saw the list of all the 5 letter strings considered 'valid' by the wordle. Indeed, the majority of these are unknown to me. However, over the last 20 days only one wordle word was unknown to me. I am wondering what the likelihood is that the 'wordle of the day' set is equal to the 'accepted words' list? Is the wordle of the day generated from a uniform sampling of the accepted words list or a subset?

For example, these are the first 10 wordle words in the wordle dictionary:
"aahed","aalii","aargh","aarti","abaca","abaci","abacs","abaft","abaka","abamp"

There are two sets, `A` and `W`. `A` contains all valid 5 letter words accepted by wordle. `W` contains the set of words chosen to be wordle of the day. We know `W` is a subset of `A`.

I either know a word or I don't know it. `K + U = 1`

For the sake of argument, let's say that I recognize 10% of the words from set `A`. Thus `Pr(K | A) = 0.1`.

Of the last 20 wordles of the day, I was familiar with all but one. Thus `Pr(K | W) = 0.95` with an N of 20.

My question is - what is the likelihood `W = A`?

Comment: Very low, I think. I would be annoyed if the answer was something like "abaft." But when the answer is something simple like "store" and I fail to get it, that's all on me.

Answer (score 0):

Not a maths wiz but I'm sure the set W is at the moment a curated list, probably based on words with most occurrences in literature or web content in general. n(W) could be < 0.1* n(A)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).